# Pandas: copying some values between dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, copy

I have two dataframes, called Old and New.  Old has 96 rows, and New has 48 rows.  I want to take one column of Old, say `['Values']` and split it into two columns in New, say `['First']` and `['Second']`.  Thus, for a simple example with 6 rows to start; from:

```
   Values
1    10
2    20 
3    30
4    40
5    50
6    60
```

to

```
    First  Second
1     10     40
2     20     50
3     30     60
```

I have a notion that this should be trivially easy, and yet I can't do it because the indices need to be changed.  I simply want to copy values, as you see.

How is this best done?

Comment: What if there is odd number of rows? Say seven rows. How would like to split it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use reshape:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(-1,2, order='F'), columns=['First','Second'])
Out[12]: 
array([[10, 40],
       [20, 50],
       [30, 60]], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split` from numpy, you can split into two or other size and combine them with `hstack` to form new `dataframe`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values': {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30, 4: 40, 5: 50, 6: 60}})
print(df)
```

Input dataframe:

```
   Values
1      10
2      20
3      30
4      40
5      50
6      60
```

Now, using [split()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.split.html#numpy.split) then, using [hstack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html#numpy.hstack):

```
splits = np.split(df, 2)
result_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(splits), columns=['First', 'Second'])
print(result_df)
```

Result:

```
   First  Second
0     10      40
1     20      50
2     30      60
```

*Without using intermediate `splits` variable, you can try:*

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack(np.split(df, 2)), columns=['First', 'Second'])
```